# How To Determine the tar Command Used To Create An Existing tar File

Tags: linux, debian, tar

I am trying to recreate the process used to create a tar file we use.

The tar file contains what appears to be a group of files filtered from all over the file system. I don't know if the original command used --exclude or --include or a combination of both or perhaps a file containing the paths.

I could easily use the existing tar as a template to grab the same files, but if --include or --exclude were used, I would probably miss some or include others that should not be in the tar.

Does the tar file include info I can use to recreate the original command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. One `tar` archive can be created on many ways and produce the same result.

For example you can create `tar` with one command or you can create it with specific list of files and then update it adding new files, etc.